# Adding a new field to body of the request from Netflix Zuul Pre-filter

Tags: filter, netflix-zuul, netflix

I'm trying to add a new field to request's body, in a Zuul Pre-filter.

I'm using one of the Neflix's Zuul sample projects from [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-zuul-filters/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/samplezuulfilters), and my filter's implementation is very similar to `UppercaseRequestEntityFilter` from this sample.

I was able to apply a transformation such as uppercase, or even to completely modify the request, the only inconvenient is that I'm not able to modify the content of body's request that has a length more than the original length of the body's request.

This is my filter's implementation:

```
@Component
public class MyRequestEntityFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
        return true;
    }

    public Object run() {
        try {
            RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
            InputStream in = (InputStream) context.get("requestEntity");
            if (in == null) {
                in = context.getRequest().getInputStream();
            }

            String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            body = body.replaceFirst("qqq", "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");

            // body = body.toUpperCase();

            context.set("requestEntity", new ServletInputStreamWrapper(body.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            rethrowRuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the request that I'm doing:

[image: Request Sample]

This is the response that I'm receiving:

[image: Response]

Comment: Please don't post images of code in SO (read [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) if you wonder why)

Answer (score 7):

I was able to obtain what I wanted, using the implementation of PrefixRequestEntityFilter, from [sample-zuul-examples](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-zuul-filters/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/samplezuulfilters/PrefixRequestEntityFilter.java):

```
@Component
public class MyRequestEntityFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
        return true;
    }

    public Object run() {
        try {
            RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
            InputStream in = (InputStream) context.get("requestEntity");
            if (in == null) {
                in = context.getRequest().getInputStream();
            }

            String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            body = body.replaceFirst("qqq", "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");

            byte[] bytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8");

            context.setRequest(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(getCurrentContext().getRequest()) {
                @Override
                public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                    return new ServletInputStreamWrapper(bytes);
                }

                @Override
                public int getContentLength() {
                    return bytes.length;
                }

                @Override
                public long getContentLengthLong() {
                    return bytes.length;
                }
            });

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            rethrowRuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone looking at this solution, pay attention to the fact you should have both getContentLength() *and* getContentLengthLong() on your request wrapper. I was missing the getContentLengthLong() and couldn't work out why my modified request body was still being truncated to the old content length.