# Modify request header in zuul filter

Tags: httprequest, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a backend service which accepts Authorization header to validate access. I created a Gateway service with Spring cloud zuul and routed requests to backend service.

Gateway service itself is protected with OAuth2 and accepts a Authorization header to validate access. Now once the request authorizes to gateway service, Gateway service act as a client to send an updated Access token in the header by using it's clientid,secret and backend service resource ID. As it has to send Authorization header, I was trying to update the Authorization header in the request but it is taking for below two ways.

```
ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
```

With the above code it is adding Authorization header but it is adding it to zuul headers which the backend service is not identiyfying.

I have created a wrapper to modify the request object but it is not working

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
{
    private final Map<String, String[]> modifiableParameters;
    private Map<String, String[]> allParameters = null;

    public RequestWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request, 
                                                    final Map<String, String[]> additionalParams)
    {
        super(request);
        modifiableParameters = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
        modifiableParameters.putAll(additionalParams);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(final String name)
    {
        String[] strings = getParameterMap().get(name);
        if (strings != null)
        {
            return strings[0];
        }
        return super.getParameter(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()
    {
        if (allParameters == null)
        {
            allParameters = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
            allParameters.putAll(super.getParameterMap());
            allParameters.putAll(modifiableParameters);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(allParameters);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames()
    {
        return Collections.enumeration(getParameterMap().keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(final String name)
    {
        return getParameterMap().get(name);
    }
}
```

Above wrapper is found from http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/how-to-safely-add-modify-servlet-request-parameter-values/
and called it in the zuul filter

```
    authToken = getAuthToken();     
    String accessToken = "Bearer " + authToken;
    Map<String,String[]> additionalParams = new HashMap<>();

    additionalParams.put("Authorization", new String[] {accessToken});     
   ctx.setRequest(new RequestWrapper(request, additionalParams));
```

What am I doing wrong or any other way of modifying request header?

Answer (score 5):

if you are asking about how to add headers to Zuul request, your code is correct but you should verify the Filter type (Pre, Route, Post, ...) and the **ORDER** of your filter.

Check this thread : [Adding Headers to Zuul when re-directing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040703/adding-headers-to-zuul-when-re-directing/50063074#50063074)

And maybe this can helps too : [How to select route based on header in Zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538352/how-to-select-route-based-on-header-in-zuul/48558556#48558556)

If you need to pass authorization through Zuul to backend service, you can check `sensitiveHeaders` property. Something like :

`zuul.routes.YOURSERVICE.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie`

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811480/adding-a-new-field-to-body-of-the-request-from-netflix-zuul-pre-filter